# Sideloaded Wear Os App On Device But Can't Launch It

Tags: adb, side-loading, android-wear, google-family-link

I am trying to gift my watch to my 10 yr old. However, google doesn't allow kids to install the wear os app, so I am trying to hack around it. I have installed it successfully to the device (pixel 3 running android 11) using adb install, and I can see it in the settings app list. However, I cannot find any way to add it to the app drawer or launch it. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: have you ever managed to get this working?

Comment: nope. my old android watch is a paperweight until she is 13. only solution would be to get her an apple watch in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier to just edit your son's birth date in his Google account?
https://myaccount.google.com/personal-info

Comment: but that defeats the entire family link restrictions entirely, which i don't want to do. i still want restrictions on all other apps besides wear os.